# Babel 5 plugin is being run with an unsupported Babel version

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

After I installed `relay-query` plugin with `yarn add -D babel-plugin-react-relay`, and after running the dev server, I get this error:

```
Error: [BABEL] /Users/nemanja/sites/tictacturing/src/index.js: The (relay-query) Babel 5 plugin is being run with an unsupported Babel version. (While processing: "/Users/nemanja/sites/tictacturing/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-relay/lib/index.js")
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
```

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "tictacturing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^6.1.0",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.5",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt": "0.4.14",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.0.6",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^6.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-relay": "^1.7.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.9",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjoyiidl5gzv901148dsyafg1 node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjoyiidl5gzv901148dsyafg1 node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "react-relay"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-relay": "^0.10.0",
    "babel-plugin-relay": "^1.7.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2"
  }
}
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you solve it? I got the same errors.

Comment: Hi @Telepresence, Nemus. Did you solve this issue. I get the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671393/babel-5-plugin-is-being-run-with-an-unsupported-babel-version-tried-to-update-b

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using react16 there is no need to eject to add the custom environment variable. Your custom environment variable must begin with **REACT_APP_** in your script. This will solve the compatible issue.

```
    {
  "name": "tictacturing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-router": "^3.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjoyiidl5gzv901148dsyafg1 react-scripts start",
    "build": "REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjoyiidl5gzv901148dsyafg1 react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-relay": "^0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an upgrade for graphQL that is not applied in relay.
so for running the react application, you can use the previous version:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cixqegi9u003g0196b2rtnhqu node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cixqegi9u003g0196b2rtnhqu node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
```

Answer (score 0):

you shoud install babel by npm instead of yarn like below:

**npm install -D babel-plugin-react-relay**