# Babel 5 plugin is being run with an unsupported Babel version. Tried to update babel-relay-plugin

Tags: reactjs

Doing *Lynda - Building and Deploying a Full-Stack React Application* tutorial, and get stuck at a point, get following error:

```
./src/index.js
Error: [BABEL] /Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/ticket/src/index.js: The (relay-query) Babel 5 plugin is being run with an unsupported Babel version. (While processing: "/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/ticket/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-relay/lib/index.js")
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
```

I tried suggestion written here: https://github.com/facebookarchive/relay-starter-kit/issues/74

`npm i babel-relay-plugin@latest --save`

It did not help, give same error.

[image]

Dependencies from package.json here:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "1.13.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.1",
    "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.11.0",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.8.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.5.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router": "3.0.2",
    "resolve": "1.12.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.4.1",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.2",
    "url-loader": "2.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.39.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  }

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-relay": "^0.10.0"
  }
```

Comment: try to install the latest version of the babel-relay-plugin. npm install babel-relay-plugin@0.11.0 --save-dev

Comment: Hi @SainPradeep! Tried both `npm i babel-relay-plugin@latest --save` and `npm install babel-relay-plugin@0.11.0 --save-dev`, but the same issue arise.